# Can't remove my home directory from URL path?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, url, path

I was troubleshooting a mysql connection problem months ago, and followed someone's instructions where they added this "pid-file edit" to the bottom of the "my.cnf" file:

```
pid-file = /usr/local/var/mysql/{username}.pid
```

I saved the changes but it did nothing, so I ended up fixing the problem myself. But now the {username} part (which is the home directory) shows on all my URL paths. It gets bothersome so I want to remove it but can't, since I don't even remember which file I made the pid-file edit to. I used this to find the my.cnf file -

```
sudo find / -type f -name "my.cnf"
```

But it doesn't show on it where I made the edit. I then manually searched the entire "/usr/" directory in case of another my.cnf file and still nothing. I even checked inside the ".pid" file and it doesn't show the edit in there either. So does anyone know how I can officially get rid of the ~{username} that shows in my URL? It currently looks like this -

http://localhost/~username/webfolder

but I want it to look like this:

http://localhost/webfolder

Thanks for your help

Comment: There's no reason the name of the pid file (or anything else in the MySQL config, for that matter) would have anything to do with your URL paths. You need to configure your webserver, not MySQL.

Comment: So how would I do that?

Comment: Figure out what webserver you have, then set the `DocumentRoot` (Apache) or `root` (nginx) in the configuration.